# What causes the number keys to stop working on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard

In recent weeks a new problem has surfaced on my work PC. The number keys along the top of the keyboard, **not the numeric keypad**, occasionally stop working. Strangely it is not the entire row of keys, only the 1/! to 0/) that stop working. The `/~ key to the left and -/_, =/+ and backspace keys in the same row still work. Both the shifted and un-shifted modes stop working.

I don't believe it is a hardware or firmware fault with the keyboard but some kind of software issue as it is resolved by a reboot. I know that there is an option that can prevent the keys on the numeric keypad from working as normal while controlling the mouse pointer but not of anything that could affect the normal number keys.

Does anyone have any ideas of what might be causing it?

To clarify why I don't think it is a hardware fault, this is happening infrequently; only three times in the last while and each occurrence has been at least a week apart. I don't see how the keyboard would work fine for ages then suddenly exhibit this behaviour only to work fine again after a reboot.

**Update: The problem seems to be related to a bug in the Windows 10 PowerToys application. See accepted answer for link to GitHub issue.**

Comment: Have you tried a new keyboard? Maybe it is a hardware issue.

Comment: See my update above explaining why I don't think it's a hardware fault. But this is one of two identical mechanical keyboards I own. The other being at home. I will swap them and see if the problem moves to the other computer, but I think it's not likely.

Comment: To rule out software problem, boot the machine with a live linux distro and check the keyboard. No need to install, just live boot.

Comment: Did you have a Windows update during these recent weeks?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same problem and it seems to be the FancyZones part of Microsoft Powertoys that somehow makes the number keys stop working. I solved the problem by closing Powertoys and reopening it.

Hope this helps

Found [Issue #410: PowerToys steals my number keys!](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/issues/410) that confirms this is likely what caused my problem.

Comment: This is the first answer that I think may point to the actual cause. I do indeed have that Powertoy installed. I tried it but haven't really been making use of it so will just uninstall it.

Comment: Found the issue on the Powertoys GitHub so will edit your answer to include it and mark it as the approved answer.

Comment: [PowerToys Release v0.14.0](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/releases/tag/v0.14.0) resolves this bug: "Fixed the FancyZones bug that was stealing the number keys (mostly happening when dragging Chrome tabs)."

Comment: This problem has been plaguing me for months. I'm so relieved to finally find the cause of this. THANK YOU!

Comment: I have been having this issue for months, thanks

Answer (score 1):

To delete/uninstall the drivers from the registry follow these steps:-

1. Press  <kbd>Win</kbd>  +  <kbd>X</kbd>
2. Choose Device Manager.
3. In the list of given items,open the keyboard section.
4. Right click on the keyboard that is shown and click Properties.
5. In the details tab, select the property to Class Guid.
6. Now open Windows Registry( press <kbd>Win</kbd> +  <kbd>R</kbd>  and type **Regedit** and hit  <kbd>Enter</kbd> )
7. Press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>F</kbd>  and paste the value and hit  <kbd>Enter</kbd> .
8. Press  <kbd>F3</kbd>  (Finds the next item) till you find something named “DriverInfName” that has Type “REG_SZ” and has the Data as “keyboard.inf”(This would be found on the right side of the window).
9. Delete the entire folder which would be highlighted on the left side of the window(It would be a tree structured list).
10. Close the registry(wait for it as it might be doing some changes).
11. Remove the keyboard.
12. Restart the computer and before restarting connect the keyboard back again(Note:The start up may take longer than expected as it would be installing the driver).

**Note:Your keyboard may not work after this process,It did work for me but only do so if you have an extra keyboard**

If you don’t wish to do the aforementioned,to uninstall from the driver from device manager,follow the above steps till 3 and follow these steps after that:

1. Right click on the keyboard present and click uninstall driver.
2. Restart the computer and wait to see if the problem still occurs and only then risk it for the registry uninstall.

Comment: Not going to do this. The occasional nature of the problem doesn't really point to a hardware or driver problem and another answer has identified a piece of software that might be the cause. I will rule that out before considering any other options.

Comment: @SteveCrane Sure

Answer (score 0):

Fancy Zones in Power Toys was indeed the culprit.
Disabled the feature and killed the process; all works as before.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1113416)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late and made an account just to give my particular solution if this happens to anyone who doesn't have Power toys and is experiencing the same problem.

If you happen to have a Logitech Mouse, it seems that using the **Game Detection** option (from the logitech gaming app) messes up with this particular section of the keyboard when switching via alt+tab from game apps to desktop too frequently and in a short period of time.

I've noticed this because when i got the mouse (502 Hero), i was using the internal storage option, therefore, i had to manually change the profile and since i didn't know how to add a key to a mouse button (i.e, change dpi function to a letter or number from top keyboard), i think there was no scenarios to make this problem to happen.

Hence, when i tried the game detecion option and been able to add letters/numbers I think I might cause the problem by not giving time to the app to refresh properly the profiles.

My solution in short was just switching the game detecion option to internal storage, top number keys started to function properly again without needing to restart anything, switching viceversa (internal to game) didn't make this problem to reappear. But as a side note i think this can be avoided by not abusing of alt+tab when using different profiles

**Update: After shutting down my pc this issue happened again, i forgot that I did exit all razer apps i currently have (synapse and cortex) before doing what is above, therefore, it seems that this issue is related to keyboard management apps, after exiting razer apps again the issue is fixed again.**

One thing I recall and noticed last night while trying to fix this is that the keyboard tab (where you can manage keyboard functions, macros, gaming mode and hypershift) in razer synapase, was not working as i wasn't been able to switch profiles, there were no profiles showing, unable to change standard to hypershift.

A posible solution can be to disable razer apps from start up and opening them manually