# Why would my Windows 10 stop registering keypresses on the numbers row?

Tags: windows, keyboard, unresponsive

In the past few months, my laptop has started randomly not accepting any keypresses on the numbers row every few days or so. Everything would work as usual and then, all of a sudden, I won't be able to use these keys.

For instance, I'd try to press 2, 4 or even ( and $ and nothing will register, as if I pressed nothing. I have two keyboards (laptop's and external) and when this happens, *neither* of the numbers rows on *neither* of the keyboards will work at all. The Numpad works as usual.

I cannot seem to replicate this; it happens randomly and I haven't found a pattern so far. 
The only way I've found to fix it is to reboot the laptop.
I've checked stickykeys et al, but those don't seem to be on when this happens. I've also tried disconnecting the external keyboard and my external monitor, but that makes no difference.

Any ideas on what could be causing this and/or how to fix it without rebooting?

Comment: Does the external keyboard work properly (all keys)?  If Sticky Keys and Accessibility features are for certain not enabled and if the external keyboard works, then the laptop keyboard is defective.

Comment: maybe you have some "function lock" key that turns the top rows into function keys.  Do they have alternate symbols printed on them in addition to their normal ones?  Like does the 2 key on the laptop have more than just "2" and "@"?

Comment: to explain why I am asking something so simple:   the numeric keypad sends different key codes than the normal number keys, but the two keyboards both send the same.  So if some sort of software installed by your laptop vendor is switching into another "mode" to remap these keys it might get both keyboards.

Comment: You have a good suggestion, but that does not explain the randomness of the issue (from what I can see).

Comment: @John, the rest of the keys on the external keyboard work okay but not the numbers row. Sorry if that was unclear in my original post – do you have any suggestions on how to make it clearer?

Comment: @AmmoGoettsch, there aren't any alternate symbols on the numbers row of the laptop, and nothing changes when I unplug the external keyboard either (once this starts happening).

Comment: At this point, consider a Windows 10 Repair Install. Use the second link (download and run in place) in the Media Creation link. At the appropriate spot, choose Keep Everything. I always make sure I have a current backup.   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Try doing this and please read the warnings and instructions carefully before trying the following:  https://superuser.com/a/1505288/1062246

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would still search your installed programs for any sort of keyboard utilities installed by the laptop vendor or installed by you later.  The fact that it happens to exactly 100% of the top row on both keyboards means it is probably a piece of software capturing these key codes and trying to do something clever like "media keys" or something like that.  I have a hard time imagining any sort of corruption or install problem that would affect exactly that set of keys regardless of which device sends them.

It fully explains why the numpad works like I said above, those keys send an extended scan code that is different from the normal number keys.

Comment: Thanks, @Ammo! I've tried all the background programs I had running and it turns out it was one of the settings in MS's PowerToys ver 0.12.0 – not sure which one but the functionality returned as soon as I stopped that running.